# Get position/index of a JPanel in a GridLayout?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, mouseevent, grid-layout

I'm trying to follow MVC-design and currently creating a MouseAdapter in my Controller class. I have an array the same size as the GridLayout in one of my model classes.
So when someone clicks a JPanel somewhere in the grid, I'd the MouseAdapter to notify the model and do something. The JPanels are in another class, View.

But for that I need the index/position of that particular JPanel, is there some way to get it?

I checked out the GetX and GetY methods of MouseEvent which state:

GetX -  Returns the horizontal x position of the event relative to the source component.

Get Y - Returns the vertical y position of the event relative to the source component.

Relative to the source component, does that mean that the upper left corner of the JPanel is 0, 0? How then do I know which of the panels in the GridLayout was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Map in your view class and a create a method

```
public void getJPanelPos(JPanel panel)
```

to retrieve the position of the JPanel source of tyhe event

Answer (score 0):

Put the information you require in the mouse listener that you add to the component. It's easier to do this in the set up than having mappings and look ups.

Comment: How do I put something I don't have? I don't know which JPanel will be clicked, that's why I need the index.
When you add the GridLayout you do something like setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8)). I need those two numbers for the particular JPanel that is clicked. Is there some way to loop through the grid as if it was an array, using two for loops? Then maybe compare each element with event.getSource()? The JPanels are probably not unique though, so might not work that way.

Comment: I'd tend to orgnanise it like this: Loop across rows (and columns) calling a method to add each component. `for (int row=0; row<rowNum; ++row) { add(row, col); }`. Define `add` as `private void add(final int row, final int col) { Component comp = new Component(); comp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) { ... do something with row and col ... }}); container.add(comp); }`

Comment: Hmm that could work, but the MouseAdapter is defined in a class separate from the one with the JPanels. A question, two "different" JPanels always refer to two different objects right? Even though if they have the same color etc? Because then I could create an array of JPanels and create a reference between each JPanel and each JPanel that is added to the GridLayout, then just compare getSource() and the reference and see if they refer to the same object and from there get the index from the variable array?

Comment: I tried what I said, but to do that I had to add a reference to both the model and view class in my controller, is that bad in terms of MVC design?